# Choosing 2 variables to solve 2 equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I got two equations looking like this:

$$a\cdot c - b\cdot d = 1$$

and

$$a\cdot d + b\cdot c = 1$$

How do I choose $c$ and $d$ such that both equations are true?

Comment: Solve for $c$ from $1$ equation, then substitute that into another and solve for $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply both sides of the first equation by $a$ and both sides of the second equation by $b$:$$\begin{cases}ac-bd=1\\bc+ad=1\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}a^2c-abd=a\\b^2c+abd=b\end{cases}$$
Adding, we get $(a^2+b^2)c=a+b$ so that $\boxed{c=\frac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}}$.

Multiply both sides of the first equation by $b$ and both sides of the second equation by $a$:

$$\begin{cases}ac-bd=1\\bc+ad=1\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}abc-b^2d=b\\abc+a^2d=a\end{cases}$$
Subtracting, we get $(a^2-b^2)d=a-b$ so that $\boxed{d = \frac{a-b}{a^2+b^2}}$.

So we have shown that
$$\begin{cases}c=\dfrac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}\\d = \dfrac{a-b}{a^2+b^2}\end{cases}$$
(provided $a^2+b^2$ is not zero, so that the indicated divisions can be performed--in the real case this amounts to $a$ and $b$ not both zero).

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely clear to read

Comment: I wonder what happens if $a,b,c,d$ might be complex (then $a^2+b^2=0$ could occur even when $a,b$ not both zero..)

Comment: @coffeemath: I assumed everything here is real, given the level of OP's question. I can amend the answer to account for that. The only proviso is that you don't divide by zero, of course.

Comment: MPW-- over the complex numbers, if the system is looked at as a linear system in the variables $c,d$ [possibly complex] then *if* $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ the solution is unique (matches yours), while if that sum of squares happens to be zero and one finishes via row reduction it gets to either the second row saying $0=N$ with nonzero N, or else eventually to $a=b$ which with the sum of squares zero then gives $a=b=0,$ so again no solutions. Conclude no solutions in complex values other than the solution you have in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out that, if $u=a+bi,$ and $v=c+di,$ (complex numbers), then the system is equivalent to $u \ v=1+i$ so one may take any nonzero complex $v$ and then compute $u=(1+i)/v.$

*Added note:* The above assumes one wants only the solutions with $a,b,c,d$ all real numbers. There are likely more solutions if some or all may be complex, haven't checked on that (yet) but may return to that question.

*Added explanation (at request of OP)* Using $i^2=-1$ as usual in complex numbers, if one multiplies out $u  \cdot v$ using foil, it becomes $(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i.$ Also two complex numbers $p+q i$ and $r+s i$ are by definition equal iff both $p=r$ and $q=s$ are true. So in your problem your system is the same as saying that $u \cdot v=1+1i.$ In my answer I was getting $a,b$ in terms of $c,d$ but your question wants $c,d$ values, so change my answer to computing $(1+i)/(a+bi).$ The latter is best done via multiplying numerator and denominator of that fraction by the conjugate $a-bi$, and then you find on calculating the same result as from the other answer.

Comment: Oh, I see now why in the hint section of the exercise they pointed out that there is a connection to complex numbers. I am not very experienced with them, but if you mind elaborating, how is it equivalent to u*v = 1 + i ?

Comment: @M3xr I've added a section explaining the connection.

Comment: Thats excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To solve $a\cdot c - b\cdot d = 1$ and $a\cdot d + b\cdot c = 1$ take the first and rearrange for $c$:

Lets use elimination to get rid of$c$:

$a\cdot c\cdot b - b^2\cdot d = b$ and $a^2\cdot d+b\cdot c\cdot a=a$

So $d\cdot b^2+d\cdot b^2=a-b$

Hence $d=\frac{a-b}{a^2+b^2}$

Next use elimination to get rid of $d$:

$a^2\cdot c - b\cdot d\cdot a=a$ and $a\cdot d\cdot b+b^2\cdot c=b$

So $c\cdot a^2+c\cdot b^2=a+b$

Hence $c=\frac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}$